# Test whether a non-Emacs system process is running and, if so, kill it

Tags: subprocess, proced

I'm running Emacs on Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS with the GNOME desktop and Xorg window system.  I launch a file previewer located at `/usr/bin/sushi` with:

```
(start-process "proc-name" nil "/usr/bin/sushi" FILENAME)
```

After the previewer application launches successfully and remains open, the the Emacs process finishes and there are no active processes running through Emacs.  I.e., `M-x list-processes` shows nothing active.

The process associated with `sushi` can be seen with `M-x proced` with a line as follows:

```
lawlist 13352  5.5  0.9  11:06 00:00 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/libexec/org.gnome.NautilusPreviewer
```

The above-process can be killed manually using the `M-x proced` buffer interface.

Using Emacs, how can I programmatically test for whether this particular process is running and, and if so, kill it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list-system-processes` and `process-attributes` (untested):

```
(let ((pid (delq nil
                 (mapcar
                  (lambda (pid)
                    (if (string-equal
                         "sushi"
                         (assoc-default
                           'comm (process-attributes pid) nil ""))
                        pid))
                  (list-system-processes)))))
  (if pid (signal-process (car pid) 'INT)))
```

Comment: Using the `sushi` example, the cons cell for the `comm` key is `(comm . org.gnome.Nauti)`, and the cons cell for the `args` key is `(args . /usr/bin/gjs /usr/libexec/org.gnome.NautilusPreviewer)`.  Once those expected values are ascertained, either cons cell can be tested.  Prior to initiating the question of this particular thread, I had to spin my wheels for quite a bit of time to figure out that the `sushi` application launches the `...NautilusPreviewer` ..., as I had been looking for the word `sushi` in the active list of processes.  Thank you for your help -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses a command-line utility `pgrep` with the `-f` argument to search for a process matching a specified command line, and the utility `kill` is used to terminate a known PID:

```lisp
(let* ((command "pgrep -f \"/usr/bin/gjs /usr/libexec/org.gnome.NautilusPreviewer\"")
       (pid (replace-regexp-in-string "\n$" "" (shell-command-to-string command))))
  (if (not (equal "" pid))
    (call-process shell-file-name nil nil nil shell-command-switch
                  ;;; Yes, we could have just used:  (concat "kill " pid)
                  (mapconcat 'identity (list "kill" pid) " "))
    (message "Cannot locate PID!")))
```